# google drive api - list files shared with me in app with read and write permissions only to files created by app (permissions auth/drive.file)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm doing tests to share files with Google apis I already have how to share the files with someone ams as far as I understand is shared with user permission as reading or writing that is what I need through an app, on the side of the person to whom the file was shared I can not see it as far as I have noticed the api does not consult the files for read permissions in drive in the app just set the permission as "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" Because I just want my app to have access to the files that she created.

owner (list in api) --> shared --> user (not list in api)

```
/////////CODE SHARED FILE OWNER

var request1 = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '/permissions',
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sTokenDrive
        },
        'body':{
          'role': 'writer',
          'type': 'user',
          'emailAddress' : 'user@gmail.com'
        }
      });
      request1.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      });



////////CODE LIST FILE USER


<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for drive.files.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      "corpus": "user",
      "q": "sharedWithMe = true"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Comment: Users control who else can access their files through access control lists, represented as a list of [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-permissions) for each file.

Comment: after sharing with write or read permissions in Google Drive the user shows it but the app does not list it unless it changes the permissions that are granted to the app by accessing all the files of the drive

Comment: means we must add 'drive.readonly' beside 'drive.file' to check all stuff on 'shared with me', how ridiculous and worked at least